# Why can't weak interaction bind neutrino and electron together?

Tags: electrons, standard-model, neutrinos, weak-interaction, leptons

According to [wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weak_interaction), unlike the other three interactions, weak interaction does not produce bound states. However, according to [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/77196/) and [this](http://www.quora.com/Quantum-Field-Theory/Quantum-Field-Theory-Why-do-particles-of-odd-integer-spin-generate-forces-which-can-be-both-attractive-and-repulsive-whereas-particles-of-even-integer-spin-only-attract), the weak force should be attractive between particles with opposite "weak charges." Neutrino and electron have opposite weak isospins, so why can't weak interaction bind them together through neutral current?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can the weak force create a bound state?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/89202/)