# Can a neutrino and an antineutrino be attracted because of weak hypercharge?

Tags: neutrinos, weak-interaction

I thought that neutrinos and antineutrinos had opposite weak hypercharge. So is it theoretically possible to see a neutrino and an antineutrino form a bond between one another. Could this be because of the +1/2 isospin for the neutrino and -1/2 isospin for the antineutrino? Allowing them to bond.

Comment: I think maybe it is possible for the neutrino and an antineutrino to form a bond. However it will be pretty unstable. It might create an electron-positron pair.

Comment: Have you seen this: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/89202/can-the-weak-force-create-a-bound-state?

Comment: Okay I got it. Thanks.